# How can I do a two level sort with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string>` object that looks like this:

```
option 1
 line a
 line b
 line c
option 3
 line x
 line z
 line y
option 2
 a1
 a4
 a2
 a3
```

All the secondary details are indented one space. Is it possible to sort this list using LINQ? I only know about the very basic ordering and
don't really know where to start when it comes to trying to sort the secondary lines that have strings with a space in the first column.

Here's what I want the List to look like after sorting

```
option 1
 line a
 line b
 line c
option 2
 a1
 a2
 a3
 a4
option 3
 line x
 line y
 line z
```

I just updated the question. I had `List<string>` but it got chopped when published.

Comment: Is this a List of Lists, or are the secondary elements just in the list with the options?

Comment: In that case, you need to devise some way to link the secondary items to their primary items. Otherwise you will end up with the three primary together followed by the 10 secondary.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
yourEnumerable.OrderBy(y => y.Key).ThenBy(y => y.Prop2)
```

See the documentation at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx

**UPDATE:**
Try the code below to parse and sort, it's somewhat pseudo:

```
string lineRead;
string current;
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>);
while((lineRead = reader.ReadLine())
{
    if(!lineRead.StartsWith("  "))
    {
        dictionary.Add(lineRead, new List<string>());
        current = lineRead;
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary[current].Add(lineRead);
    }
}

dictionary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(y => dictionary[y] = dictionary[y].OrderBy(x => x).ToList());
dictionary.OrderBy(y => y.Key);
```

Comment: I think OP has a flat list of strings. :(

Comment: @Tomas - there are no Prop and Prop2 in the list. It is just a simple List<string>

Comment: @MIMI, the the problem isn't sorting it is parsing :).

Comment: Edited the answer to include som naive parsing.

Comment: This is how to do it *not* using LINQ.

Comment: @Gabe - Yes I know, but the easiest way to solve a problem isn't always with linq. For me it seems like his problem is more about parsing the linq. But I can agree that your solution is elegant.

Comment: OK, but you still haven't answered the question. How do you get the "two-level sorted" list? What you have (`dictionary.OrderBy(y => y.Key);`) only returns the top-level items, completely ignoring the 2nd-level items.

Comment: Updated the solution, but your solution is a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes, but your problem is still that `dictionary.OrderBy(y => y.Key);` returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` -- how do you turn that into `IEnumerable<string>`?

Answer (score 2):

While there's no built-in way to do this, LINQ provides a simple, elegant answer:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> Sort(IEnumerable<string> unsorted)
    {
        string option = null;
        return
            from line in unsorted
            let isSubitem = line.StartsWith(" ")
            let parent = isSubitem ? option : option = line
            orderby parent, isSubitem, line
            select line;
    }
```

The key is being able associate a sub-item (a line starting with a space) with its parent option (a line with no space at the beginning). We do this by first declaring a local variable `option` which will always hold the current parent option.

Within the LINQ expression, the first thing to do is tell it to iterate over the items in the `unsorted` input, giving each string the name `line`. Then we determine whether it's a sub-item, and put that result in `isSubItem`.

Now comes the key -- putting the parent option into `parent`. If the line is a sub-item, it just uses the stored `option`. If it's not, the `option = line` part stores the current line as `option` *and* assigns it to `parent`.

Then it's just a simple matter of sorting, first by the parent option, then by whether a line is a parent (to make sure that the parent always shows up before its children), and then by the sub-items.

If you want to use the shorter lambda-based syntax and don't want the readibility of extra names, you can do it quite simply in just a coule lines:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> Sort(IEnumerable<string> unsorted)
    {
        string option = null;
        return
            unsorted
            .OrderBy(line => line.StartsWith(" ") ? option : option = line)
            .ThenBy(line => line.StartsWith(" ") ? line : null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
                    .OrderBy(x => x.option)
                    .ThenBy(x=>x.secondary)
```

Comment: There's no option and secondary. It's just a simple List<string>

Answer (score 0):

```
list.OrderBy(<a delegate that will sort your array>).ThenBy(<a delegate that will sort your array again>)
```

is that what you wnat?

well I answered it based on your question and this is how the delegate will be, your first delegate will basically group the items under each of the options and then sort it and the next delegate will sort each of the items that fall under the option tag..

An alternate approach would be to store this in a dictionary: as follows:
Key    Value(List)
option1      a1, a2 etc
option2      as1,as2 etc
etc.

then you will sort the value and the key and then if you want put it into a list if needed only

Comment: What kind of delegate would it be? It's just a simple numeric sort.

Comment: I just updated the question. I now see that a bit of my question was chopped out when I clicked save. I added that in with code mark up.

Comment: I understood that.. I was kinda suggesting an alternative instead of dealng it the way you are.. but yea you can take the delegate approach